# R Create new date column based on times in separate date column

Tags: r, date

I have a data frame 'df' that has date and time columns and thousands of rows. For the purposes of my analysis I need any time from 17:00 hours until 600 hours the next day to count as the date as the night before. For instance, 9/16/2020 19:47 and 9/17/2020 2:45 should both count as 9/16/2020. However, 9/17/2020 19:55 would count as 9/17/2020 because the time is after 600 hours on 9/17/2020.

Here is an example of my data:

| date | rawdate | rawtime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9/11/2020 19:31 | 20200911 | 193100 |
| 9/11/2020 19:31 | 20200911 | 193100 |
| 9/12/2020 2:16 | 20200912 | 21642 |
| 9/12/2020 2:16 | 20200912 | 21642 |
| 9/12/2020 2:16 | 20200912 | 21642 |
| 9/12/2020 2:16 | 20200912 | 21642 |
| 9/12/2020 2:16 | 20200912 | 21642 |
| 9/12/2020 19:39 | 20200912 | 193900 |
| 9/12/2020 19:39 | 20200912 | 193900 |
| 9/12/2020 19:39 | 20200912 | 193900 |
| 9/13/2020 2:24 | 20200913 | 22426 |
| 9/13/2020 2:24 | 20200913 | 22426 |
| 9/13/2020 19:27 | 20200913 | 192700 |
| 9/13/2020 19:27 | 20200913 | 192700 |
| 9/13/2020 19:27 | 20200913 | 192700 |
| 9/14/2020 2:12 | 20200914 | 21246 |
| 9/14/2020 2:12 | 20200914 | 21246 |
| 9/14/2020 2:12 | 20200914 | 21246 |
| 9/14/2020 2:12 | 20200914 | 21246 |

I want to create a new column called 'newdate' that reflects these needs, so that it looks like this:

| date | rawdate | rawtime | newdate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9/11/2020 19:31 | 20200911 | 193100 | 9/11/2020 |
| 9/11/2020 19:31 | 20200911 | 193100 | 9/11/2020 |
| 9/12/2020 2:16 | 20200912 | 21642 | 9/11/2020 |
| 9/12/2020 2:16 | 20200912 | 21642 | 9/11/2020 |
| 9/12/2020 2:16 | 20200912 | 21642 | 9/11/2020 |
| 9/12/2020 2:16 | 20200912 | 21642 | 9/11/2020 |
| 9/12/2020 2:16 | 20200912 | 21642 | 9/11/2020 |
| 9/12/2020 19:39 | 20200912 | 193900 | 9/12/2020 |
| 9/12/2020 19:39 | 20200912 | 193900 | 9/12/2020 |
| 9/12/2020 19:39 | 20200912 | 193900 | 9/12/2020 |
| 9/13/2020 2:24 | 20200913 | 22426 | 9/12/2020 |
| 9/13/2020 2:24 | 20200913 | 22426 | 9/12/2020 |
| 9/13/2020 19:27 | 20200913 | 192700 | 9/13/2020 |
| 9/13/2020 19:27 | 20200913 | 192700 | 9/13/2020 |
| 9/13/2020 19:27 | 20200913 | 192700 | 9/13/2020 |
| 9/14/2020 2:12 | 20200914 | 21246 | 9/13/2020 |
| 9/14/2020 2:12 | 20200914 | 21246 | 9/13/2020 |
| 9/14/2020 2:12 | 20200914 | 21246 | 9/13/2020 |
| 9/14/2020 2:12 | 20200914 | 21246 | 9/13/2020 |

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated and save me a ton of time. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(newdate = if_else(rawtime < 70000, rawdate-1, rawdate))
```